# How to install a Windows application on Shared Hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting

So basically i am making a niche site and i want to add a video downloader into it where user adds the URL and downloads video in multiple formats.

I have a Windows application of that video downloader which is in .exe format. I am using windows based shared hosting.How to add/install that video downloader in to my hosting so that i can make it available on my site for users?

Answer (score 1):

You can't in a shared hosting environment. The default platform is all you get. If you want to customize it you need a dedicated server or some other plan where you "own" the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask your provider. Sometimes, the provider will install the application for you, provided that you sign that problems arising from the installation will not be covered by them.